# Is it possible to change the ID as an attribute in a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Html.TextBox outputs the name and id attributes. I know it is possible to change the id by adding some parameters. But, is it possible to annotate the ID in the model?

Example:

```
class Foo {

    [HtmlAttributes(Id = "NameId")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Now TextBox() will print
<input id="NameId" name="Name" ...
```

Thanks!

MVC 4, C#

Comment: I'm sure someone can interpret what you want, but not me. Can you provide some sample code, even if it's pseudo-code, to explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("name", "1", new { id = "id" })
```

To make custom annotations you would probably have to write your own Html.TextBoxCustom method which will read metadata from model and setup ID.

Comment: No, that's specifically *not* what I want! :) I want to annotate the model.

Comment: Then you have to write your own attribute and method as I wrote